# How do I adjust panning after zoom?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, zooming, viewport, coordinate-transformation

I have a view built in React. Simplified it consists of a workspace which is positioned absolute in relation to the viewport. The viewport is the same size as the browser window. Normally (but not always) the workspace will be larger than the viewport, like in the figure below.

The user can pan the workspace revealing different areas of it in the viewport. The panning sets a negative offset on the workspace in relation to the viewport expressed in pixels (PanX and PanY).

[image: Figure 1: Workspace scale 1.]

The user can also zoom in and out. Zooming is done in fixed steps, in this example with a factor of 0.25, i.e. +0.25 for zooming in and -0.25 for zooming out. This affects the scale which in turn affects the size of the workspace. In figure 2 below the user has zoomed in one step (scale +0.25).

[image: Figure 2: Workspace scale 1.25.]

Every object in the workspace scale proportionally to the workspace. In this example the green triangle represents an object in the workspace. So after zooming in, the triangle will be larger. When the object becomes larger its offset in the viewport will change. In this example it will look like it grows downwards and to the right.

What I want to accomplish is that the center of the viewport should still be centered after the user has zoomed in or out. To accomplish this I need to adjust the PanX and PanY so the viewport remains centered over the point in workspace where it was centered before the zoom.

[image: Figure 3: Workspace after zoom]

So my question is: **How do I keep the viewport centered over the same point in the workspace when zooming in and out?**

The calculation should result in new values that I can set for PanX and PanY for the workspace that centers the viewport. Keep in mind that the viewport can be positioned anywhere as long as none of its edges are outside the workspace (like in the figure below).

[image: Figure 4: viewport inside workspace]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep whatever is in the center of the screen in the center of the screen, then define:

```
const centerX = screen.width / 2;
const centerY = screen.height / 2;
```

Then when you scale by a value `scale` (e.g. 0.25 or -0.25), you need to adjust `PanX` and `PanY`:

```
PanX -= scale * centerX;
PanY -= scale * centerY;
```

I wrote a tutorial [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/pan-and-zoom/), which uses an SVG and a slightly different transformation system, but it is basically the same thing.